# Output object in json with single quotes for laravel blade?

Tags: php, json, angularjs, laravel

I'm using angular with laravel and in my blade templates I want to do a quick and dirty assignment like so:

```
ng-init="product = {{$product}}"
```

However a problem with this approach is laravel/php outputs the json in double quotes. I'm required to use single quotes due to `ng-init=""` on the outside. I've tried `str_replace('"', "'", $product)` but its only a matter of time until I run into a value with an apostrophe. Is there any solutions to this?

Note: I'm well aware that this is bad practice but its a quick and dirty solution to a couple of pages, also saves me time and the client money.

Comment: Can you give an example of the data please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use single quotes for the attribute quoting:

```
ng-init='product = {{ $product->toJson(JSON_HEX_APOS) }}'
```

...not that I condone this, but if this is what you want, this is how you do it.

Comment: Tried this first... it will "cut off" when it reaches something that has a single quote.

Comment: It should be noted that this Answer was edited (fixed) to address the Asker's initial comment. Also, Laravel's Blade implementation now provides a `@json()` directive, which is a wrapper around PHP's native `json_decode()` method, and hence accepts a second, optional argument. In other words, the same result may be obtained with `ng-init='product = @json($product, JSON_HEX_APOS)'`.